# Finding values of LRC circuit when frequency is given

Tags: ac, filter, voltage-divider, circuit-analysis

I am trying to solve the following question. The original question is:

> The given impedances of the series LRC circuit are established at an
>   angular frequency of 2000 rad/s.
>
> Calculate the **resonance** angular frequency from the given circuit and
>   calculate the current I through the inductor at resonance, given the
>   voltage across the capacitor is 4j mV at resonance.

This is my approach:

[image]

First, I think that the given impedances are when the frequency is 2000 rad/s , so I tried to find their values when the frequency is 2000 rad/s. Is the approach correct?

Then I remember the formula for finding the critical frequency was as how I wrote it in part 2 of answer. Any ideas if this is correct?

Also, I have no idea how to find the current across L at resonance. What I remember is that in resonance the impedance of C and L are canceling eachother so the given voltage should be the voltage same across the resistor. Can you check please?

Comment: 500uF is wrong for C.

Comment: @Andyaka can you explain more? why?

Comment: It's a homework question so I'm pointing out your first mistake and not solving the whole thing for you

Comment: @Andyaka no its not homework! I am too old for that lol

Comment: Given your starting point, you can simplify 2*pi*318Hz. That might make the error in C easier to spot.

Comment: Look at your final equation for C. What happened to the '8' from the line above?

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot to put that 8 in denominator....ok I got the C value to be 62.5 uF....But the question is...am I even approached this currectly?

Comment: Once you have got C correct look at the formula you have for resonance. It looks wrong. The value for L looks correct. You ARE approaching this correctly.

Comment: There are sneakier ways of getting straight to the resonant frequency based on +j6 for L and -j8 for C. But let's see what you get thru the conventional procedure. Resonance is 2309.4 rad/sec is what you are aiming for

Comment: ok, I know another formula, that is W0 = 1 / sqrt(L.C) and that gives 2309.4 as you said. what about the current through L at this frequency? will it be the same current through R that is 4j/.5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been a lot of comments but I think it's still valuable to sketch the solution:

The impedances of \$L\$ and \$C\$ are given at an angular frequency \$\omega = 2000\$ rad/s. This means that

$$\omega L = 6\Omega\text{ and } \frac{1}{\omega C}=8\Omega$$
which gives the following values for \$L\$ and \$C\$:
$$L=3mH\quad C=62.5\mu F$$

If you don't know the formula for the resonance frequency by heart, it's very easy to derive it (if you know that the impedance must be purely real-valued at resonance):

$$Z = R + j\left (\omega L -\frac{1}{\omega C} \right)$$
The imaginary part of the impedance \$Z\$ disappears for \$\omega L = \frac{1}{\omega C}\$, i.e.

$$\omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}} = 2309.4\text{ rad/s}$$

Since at resonance the impedance of the capacitor and the inductor are equal, the voltages across them must be equal. So the current through the inductor at resonance must be

$$\frac{4mV}{\omega_0 L} = 0.577\text{ mA}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot...can you tell me if they asked for current for the capacitor, would it be 4mV/W0C ?

Comment: It would be \$4mV\cdot \omega_0C\$ because the capacitor's impedance is \$1/(\omega_0C)\$ and current = voltage/impedance.